# Change the target of the hyperlink in chemnum

Tags: hyperref, chemnum

I was reading the manual for `chemnum` today and noticed the hyperlinks option for the first time. It is a great idea, so that when I reference ''Compound 4`` 30 pages after I define it, its easy to click on the link and see what it is.

However, it doesn't go to the most useful place. See, I use `\refcmpd` in the title of the section, as there is a warning in the manual about mixing \cmpd and the Table of Contents. Likewise I don't use \cmpd in figure captions.

Which means that, combined with the fact that when you click the link it places that line of text at the top of the page, what you see if a paragraph of text, and it isn't clear what you should be looking at, since the link target is nowhere near the centre of focus.

Example: Can you spot the link target? It isn't near the centre of the page (where the eye naturally goes). Nor is it any of the coloured link-targets on the page. Its the bold number in the very top-right of the page. Not shown: The figure that makes this whole thing make sense, just off the page to the top.  [image: An image showing a page of text, with the link target nowhere near the centre of focus.]

Would it be possible to change this target to instead point at the top of the section/subsection/subsubsection the compound is defined in, or at a manually set anchor point (Then I could put a \cmpdlabel command at the top of that section, so the first thing you see is the section title and opening figure?)

I *don't* want to move every link in the document since that is going to screw up the hyperlinks to figures, sections and references, which all work very well right now.

I've added a MWE that shows the problem and can be played around with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{hyperlinks=true}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Title} %Link going here, good
\label{sec:one} %I could manually set a target like this

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption[\refcmpd{a}]%
        {This figure is included in the MWE as every section starts with one.
        In fact, it is part fo the reason the first cmpd is so far down the page.
        It is one of the things I'd like to appear when the link is clicked on. \refcmpd{a}.}
    \label{fig:PictureOfA}%
\end{figure}

\cmpd{a} %Link puts this at the top of the page
\lipsum[1-2]
\cmpd{a} 


\end{document}
```

What you see right now with the MWE: [image: The same issue, with the things I want to demonstrate cut off]

What I would like to see: [image: The section title and the figure]

Edit: Turns out this does NOT work outside my MWE, and instead takes me to the first page of my thesis, so I was right to be nervous about it. Included so this isn't used as the basis for an answer.

<s>I *did* think of a way to make this work, but its...a little scary as I'm worried anchoring my numbering system to a float might backfire on me down the road.</s>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{hyperlinks=true}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Title} %Link going here, good
\label{sec:one} %I could manually set a target like this

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption[\refcmpd{a}]%
        {This figure is included in the MWE as every section starts with one.
        In fact, it is part fo the reason the first cmpd is so far down the page.
        It is one of the things I'd like to appear when the link is clicked on. \cmpd{a}.} 
        %I'm now using \refcmpd{a} in the text sent to the TOC, and \cmpd{a} in the actual caption
    \label{fig:PictureOfA}%
\end{figure}

\cmpd{a} %This is IN THEORY no longer the first link
\lipsum[1-2]
\cmpd{a} 

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following result, which seems to be the top of the page the figure is on, which is...better, but not IDEAL. For one thing, if I were to for some reason NOT have that figure as the first thing in the section, or use a wrapfigure or the figure drifts to the next page, this trick won't work anymore.

[image: Now the link takes me to the top of that page]

Comment: Have you tried \hyperlink and \hypertarget (see hyperref manual, page 18)?

Comment: Someone posted an answer in chat: I'll post it here since they have not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ulrike Fischer for this answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56249652#56249652):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\setchemnum{hyperlinks=true}

%%%%THIS IS THE CODE THAT MAKES THIS WORK
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \newcommand\cmpdtarget[1]{
        \chemnum_use_compound:n {#1}
        \chemnum_hyper_target:nn {#1}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%END OF NEW CODE

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Title} %Link going here, good
\label{sec:one}
\cmpdtarget{a} %This is the manual target

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption[\refcmpd{a}]%
        {This figure is included in the MWE as every section starts with one.
        In fact, it is part fo the reason the first cmpd is so far down the page.
        It is one of the things I'd like to appear when the link is clicked on. \cmpd{a}.} 
        %I'm now using \refcmpd{a} in the text sent to the TOC, and \cmpd{a} in the actual caption
    \label{fig:PictureOfA}%
\end{figure}

\cmpd{a} %This is IN THEORY no longer the first link
\lipsum[1-2]
\cmpd{a} 

\end{document}
```

It isn't perfect, it goes to just UNDER the section title, not to the section title itself, but its so much better then what it had before, that I'm going to use it. Thank you.